# How do i make my server connectable from anywhere?

Tags: apache2, webserver

I am new to ubuntu, I have installed LAMP stack. Now I have to make the server connectable from anywhere. How do I do that? Please explain to me in details since I have very little knowledge about networking.

Comment: This could help https://askubuntu.com/questions/197128/how-to-make-an-ubuntu-server-system-accessible-over-the-internet?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**To make your server visible from outside your LAN, you will need the following:**

- Setup NAT on your router to point port 80 to the web server (or the port your web server listens to).
- You could also use any service like DynDNS to access your webserver without having to know your public IP address. This is very usefull if your IP is dynamic and changes from time to time (or when you reboot your router).

With this changes, you should be able to access your local web server from the internet.

Comment: You should also look into Port Forwarding